# PostgreSQL 9.5 ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I have a table from which I want to UPSERT into another, when try to launch the query, I get the "cannot affect row a second time" error. So I tried to see if I have some duplicate on my first table regarding the field with the UNIQUE constraint, and I have none. I must be missing something, but since I cannot figure out what (and my query is a bit complex because it is including some JOIN), here is the query, the field with the UNIQUE constraint is "identifiant_immeuble" :

```
with upd(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k) as(
select id_parcelle, batimentimmeuble,etatimmeuble,nb_loc_hab_ma,nb_loc_hab_ap,nb_loc_pro, dossier.id_dossier, adresse.id_adresse, zapms.geom, 1, batimentimmeuble2
from public.zapms
left join geo_pays_gex.dossier on dossier.designation_siea=zapms.id_dossier
left join geo_pays_gex.adresse on adresse.id_voie=(select id_voie from geo_pays_gex.voie where (voie.designation=zapms.nom_voie or voie.nom_quartier=zapms.nom_quartier) and voie.rivoli=lpad(zapms.rivoli,4,'0'))
and adresse.num_voie=zapms.num_voie
and adresse.insee=zapms.insee_commune::integer
)
insert into geo_pays_gex.bal2(identifiant_immeuble, batimentimmeuble, id_etat_addr, nb_loc_hab_ma, nb_loc_hab_ap, nb_loc_pro, id_dossier, id_adresse, geom, raccordement, batimentimmeuble2)
select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k from upd
on conflict (identifiant_immeuble) do update
set batimentimmeuble=excluded.batimentimmeuble, id_etat_addr=excluded.id_etat_addr, nb_loc_hab_ma=excluded.nb_loc_hab_ma, nb_loc_hab_ap=excluded.nb_loc_hab_ap, nb_loc_pro=excluded.nb_loc_pro, 
id_dossier=excluded.id_dossier, id_adresse=excluded.id_adresse,geom=excluded.geom, raccordement=1, batimentimmeuble2=excluded.batimentimmeuble2
;
```

As you can see, I use several intermediary tables in this query : one to store the street's names (voie), one related to this one storing the adresses (adresse, basically numbers related through a foreign key to the street's names table), and another storing some other datas related to the projects' names (dossier).

I don't know what other information I could give to help find an answer, I guess it is better I do not share the actual content of my tables since it may touch some privacy regulations or such.

Thanks for your attention.

EDIT : I found a workaround by deleting the entries present in the zapms table from the bal2 table, as such 
    delete from geo_pays_gex.bal2 where bal2.identifiant_immeuble in (select id_parcelle from zapms);
it is not entirely satisfying though, since I would have prefered to keep track of the data creator and the date of creation, as much as the fact that the data has been modified (I have some fields to store this information) and here I simply erase all this history... And I have another table with the primary key of the bal2 table as a foreign key. I am still in the DB creation so I can afford to truncate this table, but in production it wouldn't be possible since I would lose some datas.

Comment: Looks like `upd.a` has duplicates. Yet its target `identifiant_immeuble` must be unique, given it's the on confict clause. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767369/upsert-error-on-conflict-do-update-pointing-to-duplicate-constrained-values I suspect your case is essentially similar.

Comment: @DanielVérité And yet when I replace the second part of the statement with `select a, count(a)
from upd
group by a
having (count(a) > 1 )` I still get no result, hence there is no duplicates...

Comment: @DanielVérité Besides, the problem in the mentionned case lies in the presence of an inner join, which is not the case here.

Comment: I can't figure out why postgres would detect that it affects the same row a "second time" if there are no duplicates. For your 2nd comment, left join versus inner join doesn't change whether you end up with duplicates. A left join produces the same or more rows than its inner join equivalent, it will never reduce or filter out duplicates.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767369/upsert-error-on-conflict-do-update-pointing-to-duplicate-constrained-values?noredirect=1&lq=1)? The error was triggered because the joins returns multiple time the same key (the duplicates are in the values **to be** updated, not the values already in the table)

Comment: @DanielVérité I thought that the concept of the left join was to produce the same amount of row than the immediatly previous declared table. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @JGH I'm afraid I do not understand your comment, I don't have any duplicate in the zapms table (containing the values to be updated), as mentionned, nor in the bal2 table since there is a UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: I meant the duplicates could be in what is returned by `upd()`. If the joins ends up repeating part of the rows (for instance if you have several dossier per id_parcelle), it may trigger the issue. Try `select id_parcelle from upd group by id_parcelle having count(*) >1`. If you get some result this is the issue.